# Я её не люблю так, как(,) ты думаешь, что я её люблю

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Я её не люблю таким образом, которым(,) ты думаешь, я её люблю.

> Я её не люблю таким образом, которым(,) ты думаешь, что я её люблю.

> Я её не люблю так, как(,) ты думаешь, я её люблю.

> Я её не люблю так, как(,) ты думаешь, что я её люблю.

Comment: Хм... Если бы не было союза ЧТО, запятые ставились бы. А если он есть, подойдëт случай из справочника Розенталя, где приводятся такие примеры: _Хозяйством нельзя сказать, чтобы он занимался_. Ну, то есть тот, где главная внутри придаточной. Подходит ли этот случай к вариантам с союзом ЧТО? Или эти варианты некорректны... Одно из двух.

Comment: Всë, подумал и понял.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Я её не люблю таким образом, которым, ты думаешь, я её люблю* — вводное слово можно переставить в другое место

*Я её не люблю так, как, ты думаешь, я её люблю* — аналогично, обособляет, т. к. можно переставить.

Некорректно:

*Я её не люблю так, как(,) ты думаешь, что я её люблю*;

*Я её не люблю таким образом, которым(,) ты думаешь, что я её люблю*.

[Третий пункт](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137) не подходит. Дело в том, что в примерах Розенталя — *Хозяйством нельзя сказать, чтобы он занимался… Слова эти мне неудобно, чтобы ты сказала…* — можно часть придаточного перед главной поставить внутрь придаточного, отделяя нормальным образом придаточное от главной:

*Нельзя сказать, чтобы он занимался **хозяйством***;

*Мне неудобно, чтобы ты **эти слова** сказала*.

В ваших же примерах такая перестановка **невозможна**. Союз *как* обязательно должен идти после *так*; и слово *который* обязательно должно быть после *образом* — иначе минус структура. А при перестановке главной части союзы будут портить структуру, потому что будут идти подряд.

Answer (score 1):

**Разговорная фразеология**

Правильно:

*Я не люблю ее **так**, // как **ты думаешь**, / что люблю.*

**Схема:**

*Ты думаешь, что **я люблю ее так**.*

*Я не люблю ее **так**, как ты думаешь, **что люблю.***