# Почему сложная синтаксическая конструкция делится на два основных блока (правило Лопатина)?

Tags: общие-вопросы, сложное-предложение

Из правила: ПАС под ред. Лопатина

```
В сложных синтаксических конструкциях, распадающихся 
на крупные логико-синтаксические блоки...на стыке 
блоков ставятся знаки препинания, указывающие на 
взаимоотношения блоков, при сохранении внутренних 
знаков, поставленных на своем собственном 
синтаксическом основании: Кусты, деревья, даже пни 
мне тут так хорошо знакомы, что дикая вырубка мне 
стала как сад: каждый куст, каждую сосенку, елочку 
обласкал, и они все стали моими, и это всё равно что 
я их посадил, это мой собственный сад (Пришв.) 
– на стыке блоков стоит двоеточие;
```

1. Всегда ли сложное предложение делится  **именно на два блока?** Это совсем не очевидно и поэтому часто **не учитывается** при решении пунктуационных задач. А еще чаще об этом вообще **не вспоминают**.
2. Деление на блоки отражается **в устной речи?**
3. Этот принцип касается предложений **со вставными конструкциями**? Вставки не входят в состав предложения, но постановка знаков (запятая и тире) часто бывает **несимметричной**, что видно и по произношению.

Вопрос задан по нескольким **недавним темам**, в том числе **по вставкам**, а также по предложениям с нестандартной **разговорной фразеологией**.

Answer (score 1):

1. Я думаю, что деление **на два блока** характерно для всех предложений с неоднородными (**взаимообусловленными отношениями**). В этом случае нужно выделить **основную синтаксическую** связь и подобрать для нее **нужный знак** препинания.

Деления на блоки нет только в предложениях **с однородными отношениями**, где ряд предложений с сочинительной связью может быть продолжен, например: *Поздняя осень. **Грачи улетели,
Лес обнажился, поля опустели.***

2. Деление на два блока отражается **в устной речи** интонационными средствами.
3. **Вставные** конструкции **по смыслу смещены**, как правило, к первой или второй части предложения. На письме и в устной речи это может отражаться в виде несимметричных знаков (запятая и тире) или пауз.
4. При составлении предложений **с разговорной фразеологией** нужно учитывать **их деление на два блока,** а иначе получается **набор** отдельных речевых отрезков, но **не предложение**. Это мы видим в двух недавних темах **[1](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475299/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE) и [2](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476488/%D0%AF-%D0%B5%D1%91-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D0%B5%D1%91-%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E).**

Смысл разговорной фразеологии в **упрощении книжного** синтаксиса, что должно восприниматься **на слух.**

**Сравним:**

(1) *Ваш Пётр ведёт себя не так, // **как,** / **я считаю**, / **надо себя вести**.*

Это принятый ответ, где вводное **предложение** находится внутри придаточного. Как его прочитать, разделив на две смысловые части? Второй блок содержит **вводное сочетание,** которое нужно выделить паузами, но тогда где **упрощение синтаксиса?**

(2) *Ваш Пётр ведёт себя не так, // **как я считаю,** / **надо себя вести.***

При таком оформлении второй блок делится **на две части** произносительной паузой.